# What set do these LEGO pieces belong?

Tags: set-identification

What set do these LEGO pieces belong to?
Mostly blacks and dark gray with some clear.
Two different size tires and a black door frame.

[image: photo of bag of black and gray bricks]

[image: second photo of bag of black and gray bricks]

Comment: Can you take another, clear picture of this bag please? There's a lot of Dark Bluish Gray elements and a glare doesn't help.

Comment: ok i edited this

Answer (score 1):

Set 10698 again

Keyparts:

4x12 plate (3029) in DBG

Small tire (87697) in Black

Large tire (58090) in Black